# Stop running next tests in order when one failed NUnit

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am using [an Order Attribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) to run my test one by one. I don't know how to make them stop running when on if them fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: why would you want that? Usually your tests should be independant from one another. Make them rely on each other is a really bad idea, as it's hard to maintain and understand your tests. Anyway you can manually cancel test-execution in VS.

Comment: I have really long test scenario that i have to split into smaller test cases, and unfortunately they are dependent from each other.

Comment: So this sounds like an _XY Problem_ where it is the duration of the tests that is the issue.  Consider switching to MSTest 2+ and use IAP.

Comment: duration is not a problem. Readability is.